# Availability of a database containing the proteins of Vibrio cholerae and their corresponding gene sequences

Tags: proteins, database, gene, data, pathogenesis

I wanted a list of all the proteins (amino acid sequences) and their corresponding gene sequences of Vibrio cholerae. I tried to search in patric, but the number of amino acid sequences and gene sequences do not match, as they have provided the whole genome. I need to know if there is a database where all the proteins of Vibrio cholerae and their corresponding gene sequences can be obtained in a single file or in a couple of files. Copy pasting 4000-5000 genome and protein sequences individually from the internet seems cumbersome to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to go to PATRIC > Data > Download Tool.

From the Taxonomy tree, find Vibrio cholerae, choose Type of annotation as either PATRIC/RefSeq or both, choose the type of file you want (gbk or faa) and download from there.

Comment: have tried that. the number of gene and protein sequences do not match

Comment: Did you get the genes from PATRIC or NCBI? If the number of genes do not match the genes would be more. Considering that you have non-coding sequences, rRNA and tRNA genes and also hypothetical and predicted sequences.

Comment: i got it from patric.